# JavaScript apply style to content editable text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have the following code which applies a bold effect to some selected text:

```
   richTextField.document.execCommand('Bold',false,null);
```

This works but what I want to do now is to be able to change the font size. If i just use:

```
   var strUser2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;   
   richTextField.document.execCommand('fontSize',false,strUser2);
```

it dosnt work because `<font size="1/2/3/4/5/6/7">` has been removed in HTML 5. Is there a way that I could apply the style `font-size:30px;` to the selected text or apply a class name to the selected text ***ONLY*** that would have CSS in it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way (withe `execCommand`) to get to a specific size, but there appears to be an [`increaseFontSize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands) command that you can invoke, so:

```
richTextField.document.execCommand('increaseFontSize',false,strUser2);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of this. Say OP want to specify a specific size for the increase. The command specifies *Adds a BIG tag around the selection or at the insertion point. (Not supported by Internet Explorer.)* but [reading about the `big` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/big) it is removed in HTML and suggests a CSS approach not involving `big`.

Comment: Understand that although `<big>` isn't valid in HTML5, it will still work in virtually every browser on the planet for backwards compatibility. Now, the proper way to do any formatting is with CSS, but since the OP is using `execCommand`, he is limited to using only the commands that work with it. That's why my answer starts off saying that I don't see a way to do it with `execCommand`, but doing it with JavaScript and CSS is another matter entirely.